# Why tabs text are black in flutter tabs dark mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

Have a example project with tabs but the tabs text are black with dark gray background, i need chose manualy white text color for each theme or is automatic?

The code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
                brightness: Brightness.light,
                primaryColor: Colors.cyan,
                primarySwatch: Colors.cyan
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData(
                brightness: Brightness.dark,
                primaryColor: Colors.cyan,
                primarySwatch: Colors.cyan
            ),
            home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

    // Options required
    const MyHomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MyHomePage> createState() => PageState();
}

class PageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    int counter = 0;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    title: const Text('Demo'),
                    centerTitle: true,
                    bottom: const TabBar(
                        isScrollable: true,
                        tabs: [
                            Tab(child: Text('Tab 0')),
                            Tab(child: Text('Tab 1'))
                        ]
                    )
                ),
                body: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                        Scaffold(
                            body: Center(
                                child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget> [
                                        const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
                                        Text('${counter}', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4)
                                    ]
                                )
                            ),
                            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                                onPressed: this.incrementCounter,
                                tooltip: 'Increment',
                                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                            )
                        ),
                        Scaffold()
                    ]
                )
            )
        );
    }

    void incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
            this.counter++;
        });
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextTheme is generated based on `primaryColor`, in another word, text color depends on primary color of `ThemeData`.

In your case,  `lightTheme` and `darkTheme` both having same primaryColor and therefore No difference on dartTheme and `Text` is still black on dark them.

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: Colors.cyan,
),
themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,//activate dart theme
darkTheme: ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Colors.black, //changed to black
),
```

If you need to use same theme data, consider wrapping `TabBar` with `Theme` widget and provide different data